# conditionally apply two different classes in liquid file --not working properly

Tags: class, if-statement, liquid

I have a scenario where two IF conditions in class attribute is breaking the functionality.

only one IF conditions is working perfectly without breaking the functionality.

```
<li class="{% if item.dropdown %}has-dropdown{% endif %} {% if item.active %}active{% endif %}">  
  ..........
</li>
```

Here class attribute has two IF conditions.
I want a way where without two IF conditions, we can achieve the same scenario in liquid template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to remove the `{% if %}` conditions from the `class` attribute would be to:

1. Create a liquid variable that contains the class names beforehand
2. Print the variable value inside the class attribute

```
{% assign custom_classes = '' %}
{% if item.dropdown %}
  {% assign custom_classes = custom_classes | append: 'has-dropdown ' %}
{% endif %}
{% if item.active %}
  {% assign custom_classes = custom_classes | append: 'active ' %}
{% endif %}

<li class="{{ custom_classes }}">  
  ...
</li>
```